# OLS with unobservable $\ z_i $

Tags: self-study, least-squares

$\ y_i$ = $\ α_1 $ + $\ α_2xi_2 $ + $\ α_3xi_3 $ + $\ α_4z_i $ + $\ α_5 xi_2 z_i $ + $\ ui_4 $

with E($\ u_i|xi_2, xi_3, z_i) = 0 $

$\ z_i $ is not observable but linearly depending on $\ xi_2 , xi_3 $

$\ zi = γ_1 + γ_2xi_2 + γ_3xi_3 + vi $

How can one find the partial effects of $\ xi_2 , xi_3 $ on the $\  E(y_i|x_i) $

Can the OLS estimator be of closed form? How can one show this?

Also, how can one show that $\ E(e_i)=0 $ ?

What can one conclude about $\ E(εi|xi_2, xi_3, x_2i_2, xi_2xi_3) $?

Is there a way to show that any function  for $\ xi_2, xi_3 $ is uncorrelated with $\ e_i $ ?

Comment: Added the tag and included my thoughts below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I so far got the following model - a rewritten form of the above:

$\ yi = β1 + β_2xi_2 + β_3xi_3 + β_4x_2i_2 + β_5xi_2xi_3 + ε_i $ with $\ E(ε_i|xi_2, xi_3) = 0 $

Comment: This answer will be complete if you include the correspondence between the betas and the alpha-gammas, as well as showing why mean-independence of $\varepsilon$ from the $x$'s does indeed hold.

Comment: How is that done in a accurate way. Struggling to mention all necessary assumptions...

Comment: You need to assume (which realistic_ that $E(v_i \mid x_1, x_2) = 0$

Comment: I am struggling to see why minor issues such a closed form are important. Or do you mean my solution was wrong to begin with? Sorry for asking again. Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by closed form? How can it not be?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I do not know how to show that it has to be closed form. Was is the right way to "proof" it?

Comment: BY simply writing down the formula for the OLS estimator that has the estimator on the one side of the equation and data only on the other side of the equation. It's that simple.

Comment: Suggestions did not help to clarify the problem.

Comment: How can you show that any function is uncorrelated with $ \ e_i $